# From HWND to application name

Tags: c++, windows

I would like to get the application name (i.e. `application.exe`) from a window handle `HWND` which comes from a `WINEVENTPROC` callback of a `SetWinEventHook` hook of `EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND`.

I already have the process id and try to use `GetModuleFileName` with it, but i seem to be missing something because it always returns an empty string.

```
{
    DWORD processId;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &processId);
    wchar_t appName[MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleFileName(reinterpret_cast<HMODULE>(processId), appName, MAX_PATH);
    qDebug() << processId << QString::fromWCharArray(appName);
}
```

Here is what i tried to do, but i obviously did not understood something.

Comment: You are not checking for error codes on any of the calls.

Comment: Process ID is not a HMODULE.

Comment: you need open process first by `OpenProcess` and then call `GetProcessImageFileName` or `QueryFullProcessImageName`, if use documented api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
GetModuleFileName(reinterpret_cast<HMODULE>(processId), ...);
```

Is not at all correct. A process ID is not an `HMODULE` and cannot be coerced into one like that.

What you need to do is pass the process ID to [`OpenProcess()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-openprocess) requesting the `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION` access right. If that succeeds, you can use [`QueryFullProcessImageName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-queryfullprocessimagenamew) on the `HANDLE` that is returned from *that* function.

Comment: we need only `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION` - and `GetProcessImageFileName` or `QueryFullProcessImageName` instead of `GetModuleFileNameEx`. the `GetModuleFileName` is only for current process - wrong api in all case here

Comment: `PROCESS_VM_READ` we not need, only `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION` (vista +) on xp `PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION`

Comment: @RbMm Will not include info for now unsupported Windows versions so just sticking with the `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION`

Comment: @GovindParmar First of all thanks for the help, but i can't seem to be able to use `QueryFullProcessImageName` not matter what i try to #include, i always get a `error: use of undeclared identifier 'QueryFullProcessImageName'`, I am using Qt if it matters.

Comment: @Idle - look like you use very old sdk. inside `#if (_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0600) #endif`  block this api declared. however new sdk auto set version to higest, aqt it creating time

Comment: @RbMm i am sorry but i don't understand, this is beyond my expertise, i am using the latest version of Qt Creator on windows 10 64 bit.

Comment: @Idle use you qt or not at all not play any role here

Comment: @RbMm then what does ? what should i do to remedy my problem ?

Comment: @Idle you need have `_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0600` have. or you define it itself to low version, or use very old sdk (15+ years old)

Comment: @RbMm alright i think i made it work, i added `DEFINES += "WINVER=0x0A00"` and `DEFINES += "_WIN32_WINNT=0x0A00"` in the .pro of my application. Thanks a lot for the help. I would still understand why i have to manually do that, where is the default value of `_WIN32_WINNT` and why is it not up to date ?

Comment: @Idle default value of `_WIN32_WINNT` was inside `sdkddkver.h` . `windows.h` include `sdkddkver.h` at very begin. if you not define `_WIN32_WINNT` yourself, it defined auto to highest known version in `sdkddkver.h`. so i guess - you (may be qt config) already define `_WIN32_WINNT` to low value in project setting or src code

Comment: @RbMm it seems like it yes, in `sdkddkver.h` there is `#if 
 !defined(_WIN32_WINNT) && !defined(_CHICAGO_) #define _WIN32_WINNT _WIN32_WINNT_WS03` and `#define _WIN32_WINNT_WS03 0x0502`

Comment: @Idle very strange. this look like you use very old sdk, yet from win2003 time. but in this case will be no `QueryFullProcessImageName` in your winbase.h at all.

Comment: @RbMm I don't know what to tell you, the `sdkddkver.h` comes from Qt creator, which is up to date and i installed it 3 weeks ago, it is included with the IDE `D:\Qt\Tools\mingw730_64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\sdkddkver.h`, I think Qt creator just define this version so that application by default are compatible with most windows out there.

Comment: @Idle *mingw730_64* so you use sdk not from microsoft but from another. in this is problem